# Purchase Order Tracking

Tags: linux, windows

I run a small tech business and I occasionally purchase items. Now, as of right now I am the only "employee", but I am going to be opening a shop soon. The question that comes to mind is that what systems, preferably free or open source, desktop application or web application for me to log what a person orders, how much, and who ordered it.

I know it sounds like a lot, but I can't imagine it would be too difficult to program I just don't have the time to do it.

So, basically, when someone wants something, I approve it, log it and inside the log would list:
Date the order was placed
Who ordered it
How much did it cost

Make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Been looking for something similar myself. There is lots out there that is cheap or free, but it's very time consuming to test and evaluate them all.

Am currently using GNUcash (desktop app), which is primarily accounting/bookkeeping, but it can do orders and invoicing, and keeps track of suppliers and clients. The benefit here is immediate integration of your ordering with your accounting and stock. However, I don't use the orders/invoicing side much, and the learning curve is somewhat steep.

Had also been looking at Web-based ERP stuff, but haven't really seen anything that jumps off the page just yet. [List_of_ERP_software_packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ERP_software_packages)

Comment: +1 The invoicing is the part I use the most, beside the basic checking account stuff.  It's actually pretty simple.  Define a customer.  Add jobs (if you want) to the customer.  Create invoice.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [GnuCash](http://www.gnucash.org/) is more of a bookkeeping system, but also supports invoicing, purchasing and other things.   It runs on Linux & windows - would support your immediate needs, but would grow with your new business.

Answer (score 1):

It's not free but I've heard good things about [Merchant OS](http://www.merchantos.com).  Compared to other POS type systems it's actually really cheap.  I've never used it but talked to a couple small store owners that love it.  It may not be what you're looking for but it's worth a look.  Also, it's all web based which is good/bad depending on what you're looking for.